# vbs script to send files via ftp and check/delete original files

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I'm trying to send files over ftp and afterwards check if the process was completed successfully, if it was I would delete the original files and keep only the ones sent in the destination folder on FTP.

I managed to patch up a script that connects to FTP and sends the files, but I'm not sure how to cross check original folder with the one on the FTP so I could determine if the copy was successful.

This is the code to send files over FTP, and in testing it sends successfully all the files, but I have to check before deletion

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path = "D:\test\"

FTPUpload(path)
Sub FTPUpload(path)

On Error Resume Next

Const copyType = 16

'FTP Wait Time in ms
waitTime = 80000

FTPUser = "test"
FTPPass = "testtest"
FTPHost = "ftp.test.com"
FTPDir = "/htdocs/test/"

strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)


'Upload single file       
If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then

Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)

Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)

Wscript.Echo "Uploading file " & objItem.Name & " to " & strFTP
 objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType


End If


'Upload all files in folder
If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then

'Entire folder
Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(path)

Wscript.Echo "Uploading folder " & path & " to " & strFTP
objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType

End If


If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
End If

'Wait for upload
Wscript.Sleep waitTime

End Sub
```

I would appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way but you can get a file listing via the `FTP` command and compare the results to what you're expecting. Here's an example:

```
' Create the FTP command file...
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("c:\ftp.txt", True)
    .WriteLine "USER test"
    .WriteLine "testtest"
    .WriteLine "ls /htdocs/test/"
    .WriteLine "quit"
    .Close
End With

' Run the command and capture its output...
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "%comspec% /c ftp -n -v -s:c:\ftp.txt ftp.test.com >c:\filelist.txt", 0, True
End With
```

This would create the file `c:\filelist.txt`, which you could then open and check for the existence of the file(s) you've uploaded. Of course, you can add additional args to the `ls` command to get more detailed info. For example, `ls -l` would give you the date updated as well as the file size.