# putty, grab revision, save as text, close from a batch file solution

Tags: ubuntu, putty, pscp

I'm not a programmer and need lots of help. I have pieces working, but want the complete solution. I have countless Ubuntu boxes in a closet on the other end of the building. From my desktop, I can putty into each machine. run the command , Cat /etc/Version. and write this down in an excel sheet.

I would like to create a batch file that connects, logs in, checks the version and saves the version in a text file named ip10101033.txt on my desktop and exits proper.

Comment: whynot ftp all the /etc/version files onto your desktop and catenate them and then make the excelsheet. and whats your desktop (windows/unix) and do you have **ip**s of the ubuntu boxes? then a simple **vbs** will do your job.

Comment: I was trying to automate the process, if I can get the data to a text file that meets my needs. The vba in excel can do the rest. Windows based desktop.

Comment: I have Putty figured out, I can get the cat \etc\version, but not a clue how to get the response, or in this case the version to save as a text file on the machine that ran the putty command. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer for this [vbs script to send files via ftp and check/delete original files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419917/vbs-script-to-send-files-via-ftp-and-check-delete-original-files) and instead of **ls /htdocs/test/** you give **get /etc/version** give it a different name, you dont need putty(or to ssh) for them if ftp is available on the ubuntu machines.